# ORA-00947: Not enough values. Can anyone give me solution plz

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
insert into challen_header 
values('CH9001',019001,TO_DATE('DD-MM-YYYY','12-12-95','Y'));

insert into challen_header 
values('CH865',016865,TO_DATE('DD-MM-YYYY','12-11-95','Y'));

insert into challen_header 
values('CH3965',019001,TO_DATE('DD-MM-YYYY','12-10-95','Y'));

select * from challen_header;
```

I get this error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command
>
> insert into challen_header values('CH9001',019001,TO_DATE('DD-MM-YYYY','12-12-95','Y'))
> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 13
> Error report
> SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
> 00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"

Does anyone have a solution for this? I am using SQL Developer.

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE Challen_header
(
    challen_no varchar2(6) primary key,
    s_order_no varchar2(6),
    foreign key(s_order_no) references sales_order(s_order_no),
    Challen_date date not null,
    billed_yn char default 'N' check(billed_yn = 'Y' or billed_yn = 'N')
);
```

This is the table which I want to create.

[image]

Comment: Always explicitly list the target columns in an `INSERT` statement! Then the cause of this will be obvious...

Comment: is the syntax TO_DATE('DD-MM-YYYY','12-12-95','Y')  right ?

Comment: pls post the table structure

Comment: Then what changes need to be done here.

Comment: `TO_DATE` is wrong. You should first show the date string, such as '12-12-95' - and then don't lie to Oracle by telling it the format is 'DD-MM-YYYY' when you are using two-digit year in your input string. You probably want 'DD-MM-RR'. Then - what is the 'Y' at the end of `TO_DATE`? Was that supposed to be a value for another column? You show it inside `TO_DATE`, where it makes no sense.

Comment: @praveen I posted the table structure.

Comment: So - OK; take the 'Y' and 'N' out of `TO_DATE`, and fix `TO_DATE`. Then, are you sure those dates are DAY-MONTH, and not MONTH-DAY? Do you have 12 Dec, 12 Nov, 12 Oct? Not Dec 12, Dec 11, Dec 10 - in your example?

Comment: @mathguy If I took out 'Y' and 'N' then it violates the date format and it shows error. And the dates are correct i.e 12 Dec, 12 Nov, 12 Oct.

Comment: "then it violates the date format" - this is good. As mathguy pointed out, your format doesn't match the date string. So make them match or better use a date literal from the start (e.g. `DATE '1995-11-12'`).

Comment: On a side note: Are you sure you want to allow null for `billed_yn`? Decide: Shall `s_order_no` be numeric (16865) or a string ('016865')? May it be null or is this a mistake?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's solved thanks.

Comment: Avoid `char` unless you really, really need its blank padding behaviour. Which nobody does. My advice is to stick with the standard string type, `varchar2`, and avoid weird types.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you do it more carefully and a little bit more organized. By saying that, I mean:

- name constraints; otherwise, they will get Oracle's *default* name (such as `SYS_C007618` which tells you nothing)
- if you decide to use outline constraints, then put all of them to the end of the `create table` script. Otherwise, if you "mix" columns and constraint, you easily get confused and don't see at first glance which is which
- always name all columns you're inserting (or updating, or selecting). Otherwise, you have no idea which value you're actually inserting into which column)
- pay attention to data types

  - if you're inserting strings, enclose them into single quotes
  - if you're inserting dates, use

    - date literals (which are always in `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'` format), or
    - correct `TO_DATE` function; don't make up your own syntax

Here's my suggestion, check how I did it and try to follow it.

Master table first (only the necessary column):

```
SQL> create table sales_order
  2    (s_order_no varchar2(6) constraint pk_sal_ord primary key);

Table created.

SQL> insert into sales_order (s_order_no) values ('019001');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Now, the detail table:

```
SQL> create table challen_header
  2    (challen_no    varchar2(6)      constraint pk_chall_head primary key,
  3     s_order_no    varchar2(6)      constraint fk_chall_head_order references sales_order(s_order_no),
  4     challen_date  date             not null,
  5     billed_yn     char default 'N' constraint ch_chall_head check(billed_yn in ('Y', 'N'))
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into challen_header
  2    (challen_no, s_order_no, challen_date, billed_yn)
  3     values('CH9001',
  4            '019001',           --> enclose it into single quotes
  5            date '1995-12-12',  --> date literal, always YYYY-MM-DD
  6            'Y'
  7           );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four columns in the table. You have omitted the column list in `INSERT` and then given too few values in the `VALUE` clause by mistake. Then, when inserting date constants, use date literals. It is not necessary to use a string instead and convert it with `TO_DATE`.

```
insert into challen_header 
  (challen_no, s_order_no, challen_date, billed_yn)
values
  ('CH865', 016865, DATE '1995-11-12' 'Y');
                    ^---------------^  this is a date literal
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Insert query to -

```
INSERT INTO challen_header(challen_no, s_order_no, Challen_date, billed_yn) 
                    VALUES('CH9001', '019001', TO_DATE('12-12-1995', 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'Y'));
```

Comment: No - there is also a fourth column, the 'Y' in the OP's post (he had it in the wrong place).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
insert into challen_header values('CH9001','019001',TO_DATE('DD-MM-YYYY','12-12-1995','Y'))

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that the target table has the columns according to the values to be inserted.